# React/Apollo fetchMore reloading the whole page

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have a problem trying to do a pagination / fetchMore button for a list of data on my webapp. My problem is that when I click on the fetchMore button the whole page is reloading, old school style, while I would like only the updated list of 'calculs' to be reloaded but not the rest of the query (users...).

Is there a way to limit what is updated after a fetchMore ? Don't want the whole DOM to be rerendered.

I also tried to send a specific query, only refecthing what I need, but I got an error as well.

Here is the needed part of the code:

```
export const query = gql`
    query UserAndData($limit: Int!) {
        user {
            _id,
            nom,
            prenom,
            email,
            isAdmin
        }
        adminCalculations {
            _id,
            lastUpdated,
            comments
        }
        adminUsers {
            _id,
            lastConnect,
            nom,
            prenom,
            email,
            societe
        }
        calculs(limit: $limit) {
            _id,
            userId,
            date,
            duration,
            user {
                email
            }
        }
        count
    }
`

class Admin extends Component {

    state = {
        limit : 100,
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Query query={query} variables={{ limit : this.state.limit}} fetchPolicy="cache-and-network">
                {({ loading, error, data, fetchMore }) => {
                    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
                    if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
                    console.log(data);
                    if (!data || (!data.user || !data.user.isAdmin)){
                        return (<Redirect to="/" />)
                    }
                    return(
                        <div className="admin">
  (lot of coding and rendering users list, calculs lists, etc...)

   <div className="bouton" onClick={() => {
       fetchMore({                               
          variables : { limit : this.state.limit + 100 },
          updateQuery : (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
          if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
          return Object.assign({}, prev, { calculs : 
          fetchMoreResult.calculs });
      }

                                                })
                                                this.setState({ limit : this.state.limit + 100 })
                                            }
                                                }>Charger plus de calculs</div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }}
                </Query>
            )
        }
    }

export default Admin;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is THE problem, but it is definitely problematic.   Don't set state inside a render method.  React is called React because it "reacts" to prop and state changes with a new render.  Your state is located towards the root of your example.  That high up, everything in your render() method will re-render when the state changes.

Comment: the state is set on a onClick action don't see where it's problematic, except if it interfers with the refetching ?

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried @mrbinky3000 idea and removed the setState and tried again but didn't change anything. As it is part of an onclick action I don't see how it creates an issue.

Comment: The if statement that has  `if (!data || (!data.user || !data.user.isAdmin)){` redirects to "\".  throw a console log in there to check that data.user and data.user.isAdmin exist when Apollo starts to fetch more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found out the problem was linked to my query. As I was querying the whole needed data for my Component and as I had a

```
if(loading)
```

statement, the whole page was loading again each time the refecthing was taking place and therefore the whole page was rendering the

```
<p>Loading...</p>
```

even if the loading time was very small -> that caused my full page "refreshed"

In order to solve this issue I have created a child component that include also an Apollo Query component but only the query that I want to be refetched. The parent component with the user, adminCalculations and adminUsers query is not pointlessly refreshed and only the needed child query refetches and rerenders.

Comment: Had the same exact problem, thank you for sharing your solution

Comment: Yes. the exact problem I had encountered, the `loading` state is technically changed on every fetch event besides the first render. Didn't realize that until seeing your answer. We have to be really care for about the apollo state from query